# Camel Helloworld program

Tags: java, apache-camel

```
package com.camel;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor; 
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

public class FirstRoute {
public static void main(String args []) throws Exception{
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("file:C:\\workspace\\input?noop=true").process(new     strong textProcessor() {

                @Override
                public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("hello camel!");
                }
            }).to("file:C:\\workspace\\output").end();          
        }
    });
    context.start();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    context.stop();
}

}
```

This is my first camel program. looks like every thing is correct. but the file transfer is not happening.

I added

- camel conext 2.12.1 jar
- camel core 2.12.1 jar
- camel ftp 2.12.1 jar
- slf4j api 1.7.6 jar

Comment: "Hello camel" is not getting priinted in the console and also the file transfer is not happening. So irritating that i couldnt do a small program. Please let me know why. Thanks guys!

Comment: i added Log4j 1.2.15 and slf4j-log4j 1.7.6. it works. But at times it never work. Camel is acting ver wierd. Sometimes the file is transferred, but the sysout is not happening.very confusing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

increase the `sleep` time to get the result correctly.

That `1000 ms` is not enough to copy the files from input directory to output directory.

That `sleep` time specifies a time limit to copy files from input to output. if you increase `sleep` time context will copy more files from input to output directory

Answer (score 2):

Usually when `Camel` is used as a `standalone` application, you should use `Main` provided by `Camel`. I have posted the code from their site :

```
public class MainExample {

    private Main main;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MainExample example = new MainExample();
        example.boot();
    }

    public void boot() throws Exception {
        // create a Main instance
        main = new Main();
        // enable hangup support so you can press ctrl + c to terminate the JVM
        main.enableHangupSupport();
        // bind MyBean into the registery
        main.bind("foo", new MyBean());
        // add routes
        main.addRouteBuilder(new MyRouteBuilder());

        // run until you terminate the JVM
        System.out.println("Starting Camel. Use ctrl + c to terminate the JVM.\n");
        main.run();
    }

    private static class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("timer:foo?delay=2000")
                .process(new Processor() {
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("Invoked timer at " + new Date());
                    }
                })
                .beanRef("foo");
        }
    }

    public static class MyBean {
        public void callMe() {
            System.out.println("MyBean.calleMe method has been called");
        }
    }
}
```

Refer http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html  for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
context.start();
Thread.sleep(10000);
context.stop();
```

Change this piece of code to give time for camel to move the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your code return some exception?

The problem can be the timeout 1000 is equals 1 second, is a very short time for copy a file, you can try, up the value of timeout or remove.

Follow an example without timeout:

This Class create a RouteBuilder

```
public class CamelRoute extends RouteBuilder {

   @Override
   public void configure() throws Exception {

       from("file:/opt/files-camel?noop=true")
         .routeId("file-in")
         .choice()
         .when(header(Exchange.FILE_NAME).endsWith(".xml"))
            .to("file:/opt/files-camel/xml?noop=true")
         .when(header(Exchange.FILE_NAME).endsWith(".txt"))
            .to("file:/opt/files-camel/txt?noop=true")
         .end()
       .end();

   }
}
```

This Class run a RouteBuilder

```
public class Launcher {

   public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

       Main main = new Main();
       main.addRouteBuilder(new CamelRoute());
       main.run(args);

   }
}
```